# How to attach a ChangeEvent handler to an inherited dependency property?

Tags: .net, silverlight, dependency-properties

How would you attach a propertychanged callback to a property that is inherited?  Like such:

```
class A {
  DependencyProperty prop;
}

class B : A {
   //...
   prop.AddListener(PropertyChangeCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(edited to remove recommendation to use DependencyPropertyDescriptor, which is not available in Silverlight)

[PropertyDescriptor AddValueChanged Alternative](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/)

Comment: None of the proposed solutions can be used at least directly with Silverlight.

Comment: Removed options that don't work in Silverilght. This one should, as verified by @Dimebrain

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a two way data binding between the two dependency properties?

Comment: Agreed. Seems to me to be the most straight forward way - is there a reason this isn't being proposed as a higher-ranking solution?

Answer (score 0):

@MojoFilter,

Jon's last suggestion link will give you what you're looking for: it uses weak references to register listening to changes by wrapping properties in a new object. Scroll to the bottom of "PropertyDescriptor AddValueChanged Alternative". You'll have to change the Binding code around a bit since BindingOperations doesn't exist.